# How to legend the colors in a cpairs plot

Tags: r, graphics, legend

I'm using `cpairs(data)` to show possible relationships among the six variables in a bird size and the breeding site arrival date (day, Right tarsus, Right wing, Tail length, Bill length, Bill depth)

```
my.abs = abs(cor(data))
  my.colors = dmat.color(my.abs)
  my.ordered = order.single(cor(data))
  cpairs(data,my.ordered,panel.colors = my.colors, gap=0.5)
```

I know the high correlations are shown in pink, the middle are in blue, and the weaker are in yellow, but I don't know what high, middle or weak actually means in terms of P value.

I would like to put a legend box with the P values related to each color
It is possible?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Where does the `cpairs` function come from?

Answer (score 0):

`cpairs()` doesn't have that functionality to provide the labels for the corelation matrix. I would suggest you to use `GGally` library. In that library you will find, `ggcorr()` function. In that function put the `label=True`, to visualize the corelation value.
Find more info on this blog: https://www.datacamp.com/community/blog/r-correlation-tutorial